# html5 video layout-fill angular material

Tags: angularjs, html, video, material-design, angular-material

I have the the following code:

```
<video layout-fill loop="loop"  autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto">
  <source src="walkthrough.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

however the video is displayed like this:

(white area in the sides - the blue area displays the layover when I click on `<video>` tag in chrome developer tools.)

[image]

How can I make the video fill the area, regardless of keeping the proportion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
<div layout="column" flex >   
  <video layout-fill loop="loop"  autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto">
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>   
</div>
```

[check here](http://codepen.io/ktn/pen/VaYyGK)